# shopware6 - inject data in profile page or route http://domain/account/*

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, shopware

In Shopware6, I want to write a controller for the route http://domain/account/*.
Only I have to write in eventListener or is there other possibility?
I also could not find events for this url (http://domain/account/address).

This is my current way, but this is not enough.

File : {moduleOneSubscriber.php}

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
        CheckoutRegisterPageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
        AccountProfilePageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
        AccountOverviewPageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
        AccountPaymentMethodPageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
        AccountOrderPageLoadedEvent::class => 'myFunctionName',
    ];
}
```

Comment: You can use `AddressListingPageLoadedEvent` or `AddressDetailPageLoadedEvent` depends on your needs.

Comment: I assume you wanna achieve something similar to Shopware 5 PreDispatch or PostDispatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a generic event only for all `account/*` pages, so the approach you are doing is basically correct: Collect all the events for all the account pages.

You can for example use the Symfony profiler toolbar and search in the event tab in all tree tabs for PageLoaded Events.

So you just might add the events mentioned by Valerii in the comments.

[image: Event tabs]

Another approach would be to subscribe `Shopware\Storefront\Page\GenericPageLoadedEvent` and check the pathInfo of the request passed to the event, whether you are on `account`.

```
if (!str_starts_with($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo(), '/account/') {
   return;
);

// do your thing
```

This has the advantage that if new pages are added later with the same path, you do not need to add additional events.